# ObjectBox lazyList behaviour

Tags: android, greendao, objectbox

I'm not sure I understand from the documentation how should I use the Lazy List.

1. What the different between `findLazy()` and `findLazyCached()` the function description is exactly the same.
2. Should I make a `find()` query first time and just then use `findLazy()`?

Example of using:

```
        Box<FastCacheData> box = box.boxFor(FastCacheData.class);
        LazyList<FastCacheData> build = box.query().build().findLazy();
```

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation?

Comment: Sure http://objectbox.io/documentation/queries. Lazy loading results section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What the different between findLazy() and findLazyCached() the function description is exactly the same.

They both return a `LazyList`, which will only load the member objects as they're each accessed. The difference between the two is that the cached version will cache the object so that further accesses won't result in extra loads - the non-cached version will load a fresh object every time.

> Should I make a find() query first time and just then use findLazy()

It's a question of when you want the loading to happen. If you want the whole thing loaded when the `find()` call is made, use the `find()` call. Else if you want to defer the loading to when you access the data, use the `findLazy()` call.